# How to initialize a PSQL database in docker-compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, psql

I would like to know if it's possible to execute a PSQL command inside the docker-compose file.

I have the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3' 
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
    container_name: postgres-container
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    network_mode: host
    environment:
      - LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
      - POSTGRES_DB=databasename
      - POSTGRES_USER=username
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
```

And After this is running ok, I run the following command:
`docker exec -i postgres-container psql -U username -d databasename < data.sql`

These 2 steps works fine. But I would ike to know if it's possible to make one single step.

Every time I want to run this command. It's important the database is always new. That's why I don't persist it in a `volume` and want to run this command.

Is it possible to run `docker-compose up` and also run the `psql` command?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pure docker-compose solution with volume,

```
  volumes:
    - ./data.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

According to the [dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/fc36c25f8ac352f1fea6d0e7cf8d9bd92a4e720f/9.5/docker-entrypoint.sh#L79), at start up, it will dump in every sql data in `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`

Comment: @saadi, you should consider creating another SO post to see if you can get your issue resolved.